# Is it possible to create a template instance with a non-default constructor in c++?

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to specify which constructor to use when inheriting from a template based class? It seems like a basic thing, but I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this in C++...

In the following code, I want to use a non-default constructor for the PlayerStats object when I create a PlayerActor (which inherits from the BaseActor template class).

```
class BaseStats {
public:
   BaseStats ()
   {

   }

private:
};

class MonsterStats : public BaseStats {
public:
   MonsterStats()
   {

   }

private:
};

class PlayerStats : public BaseStats {
public:
   PlayerStats(
      const bool is_new) : 
         m_is_new(is_new)
   {

   }

private:
   const bool m_is_new;
   PlayerStats(); //Don't want this being used...
};

template <class ActorStatsClass>
class BaseActor
{
public:
   BaseActor()
   {

   }

private:
   ActorStatsClass m_stats;
};

class MonsterActor: public BaseActor<MonsterStats> {
public:
   MonsterActor()
   {

   }
private:
};

// This is where I'm not sure how to tell the template to use a non-default constructor...
// I get an error saying "PlayerStats::PlayerStats": cannot access private member declared in "PlayerStats". (Which is intended, but I don't want it to try and use the default constructor...)
class PlayerActor : public BaseActor<PlayerStats> {
public:
   PlayerActor(const bool is_new)
   {

   }
private:
   PlayerActor(); // Don't use this...
};
```

Comment: Read about the [rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html)

Comment: You will have to provide *some* constructor that is public. Then explicitly call that constructor in the derived class.

Comment: The problem is that `BaseActor` doesn't _have_ a `(const bool is_new)` constructor

Comment: @MooingDuck, yes but BaseActor also doesn't have a m_is_new variable... So it shouldn't warrant a constructor that requires a value for that variable... Or at least I would hope not?

Comment: @Rick: It doesn't have `m_is_new`, but `ActorStatsClass` might, so without that constructor, `BaseActor` can't construct it's `ActorStatsClass m_stats;` member. Maybe you need a template constructor for `BaseActor`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template <class ActorStatsClass>
class BaseActor
{
public:
   BaseActor()
   {

   }

private:
   ActorStatsClass m_stats;
};
```

If this `BaseActor` class is going to have arbitrary members, it needs ways to *construct* those arbitrary members.  So it needs a generic constructor.

```
template <class ActorStatsClass>
class BaseActor
{
public:
   template<class...Us>
   BaseActor(Us&&...vs)
   : m_stats(std::forward<Us>(vs)...)
   { }

private:
   ActorStatsClass m_stats;
};
```

This uses forwarding, that whatever parameters are passed to `BaseActor`, it just passes them directly to constructing the `m_stats` member.

This allows:

```
class PlayerActor : public BaseActor<PlayerStats> {
public:
   PlayerActor(const bool is_new)
   : BaseActor<PlayerStats>(is_new)
   { }
   PlayerActor() = delete; // Note: this is better than making it private
};
```

Comment: Hmm, and if PlayerActor needs more than one parameter, I get an error (BaseActor::BaseActor function does not take 2 arguments).

Comment: You haven't provided enough details for me to understand what you're referring to

Comment: Having multiple arguments caused an error saying too many arguments. After some research I found that changing it to BaseActor(Us&& ...vs) :
      m_stats(std::forward<Us>(vs)...) resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

your template only says which type to use you need to define which constructor to use with the object itself. for example:

```
template <class ActorStatsClass>
class BaseActor
{
public:
   BaseActor():m_stats(arguments)//call a constructor of m_stats when creating an instance of this class
   {

   }

private:
   ActorStatsClass m_stats;
};
```